# How to open a jquery dialog over opened Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have opened a Bootstrap modal when a link is clicked. Now I want to open a dialog through click on another link button (the link button is in the Bootstrap modal) over the opened Bootstrap modal. The dialog is opened without any issue but Bootstrap hides this dialog. The dialog is appearing under the modal. I want to open over bootstrap, how can I do this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```js
function projectImageAttr(imageID) {
    console.log(imageID);
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 900,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        resizable: "auto",
        modal: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Check the `z-index` of the dialog in CSS and change it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that as of **version 1.10.0+**, there is an option that "appends" the dialog to a modal using the [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option. Currently using it on Bootstrap 4.

```
$("#yourDialogId").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "#yourModalId",
    modal: true,
});
```